# Is there a list of keyboard shortcuts for Octave's command window?

Tags: octave

For example it would be great to have something like <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> in most windows programs, to switch between tabs.

Comment: Nothing turns up in a google search. Octave is a programming language so I believe this is appropriate for this forum. If not please comment and I will remove it

Comment: Does this answer the question?  http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/octave/octave_3.html  Scroll down to "Cursor Motion" for the start of the shortcuts

Comment: I think this question is appropriate for SO, however, you should revise your question so it isn't a yes/no question.  Make it more open-ended, like "what keyboard shortcuts are available" or somesuch.

Comment: These are good, thanks. Wish there were a switch tab shortcut

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is being checked down so much? I'm sure other users could find the response useful, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just open the shortcuts settings. Under "Tabs" you'll see the shortcuts:

[image: Octave shortcuts]

---

I guess what you are searching is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>

Comment: Those, and Ctrl-0 and Ctrl-4 were the ones I was looking for, thanks for pointing that out